# criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo Comparing dates without time

Tags: java

I'm working with `criteriabuilder`.
I want to extract from database all lines where date is after a given date WITHOUT TAKING ACCOUNT OF TIME
The given date dateCreation is without time, for example "`2020-10-10`" in format Date.
Dates in database are with `timestamp`. Join5 is a join between tables.

**my original code is :**

```
Predicate predicateDate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join5.get("dateEvenement"), dateCreation);
```

if `dateCreation` is `20210906`, this code works partially but doesn't return lines where `dateEvenement` is `2021-09-06 10:11:45.014`

I tried converting with `SimpleDateFormat` `yyyy-mm-dd` but `criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo` doesn't work on strings.

I need probably take only the date get("dateEvenement") without time, but I don't know how to do.

Thanks for your help.
Regards

Comment: Which Java version are you using? 8+?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat`, they're obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: and mm is minutes, MM is month

Comment: I cant change format of Date ; the project is too big

Answer (score 1):

A partial overview of date time classes:

```
Date date = ...; // Old
LocalDate localDate = ...; // Days
LocalDateTime localDateTime = ...;
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ...; // Human use of date & time.
```

Getting

```
localDate = LocalDate.parse(creationDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
localDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay();
criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join5.get("dateEvenement"), localDateTime);
```

For end-of-day:

```
localDateTime = localDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay();
criteriaBuilder.lessThan(join5.get("dateEvenement"), localDateTime);
```

One should be aware of ZonedDateTime, for 23 and 25 hour days for instance, and different time zones. Depends on what you store in the persistent data.

Comment: thanksi tried your code but there is this error :Parameter value [2021-09-06T00:00] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]|

Comment: The string with T is the standard ISO toString of for instance LocalDateTime.. And evidently the old java.util.Date is still used. So forget my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `.as(Date.class)` method is needed to perform the conversion.

Replace this:

```
Predicate predicateDate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join5.get("dateEvenement"), dateCreation);
```

With this:

```
Predicate predicateDate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join5.get("dateEvenement").as(Date.class), dateCreation);
```